# Printing images on separate pages?

Tags: c#, printing

Please advice, I'm trying to print my image list one image a page. Following code prints each image overlapping the others on one page.

```
  void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {

        List<Bitmap> labels = GetLabels();


        foreach (var bitmap in labels)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the read of bitmaps outside the PrintPage event handler, make it something like this:

```
void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
   var bitmap = GetNextLabel();

   if(bitmap != null)
   {
      e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(bitmap, 0, 0);
   }

   // Will print more pages as long as there are bitmaps
   e.HasMorePages = (bitmap != null);
}
```

So the GetNextLabel() method will have to keep track of what bitmap to print next, and return null when there are no more to print.

Setting e.HasMorePages = true will print another page.  See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cwbe712d.aspx) for more details